# MySQL 4.1 Passwords

Tags: mysql, sql, database, passwords

I am connecting to a MySQL database with Visual Basic.net and am getting this error:

```
Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style password
```

I have the following SQL code to fix this problem, where canningi_cdtest is the name of the user I wish to change the password for and testpass is the password I would like:

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0;
SET PASSWORD FOR canningi_cdtest=PASSWORD('testpass');
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
#1044 - Access denied for user 'canningi'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

What do I need to do?

**EDIT**

I have run the following code, with no errors:

```
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('my_password');
```

But when I now try and connect to the database, I am still getting the error:

> Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style password

How can I connect to an SQL database with a 4.1 password? Do I need to update cPanel? My version is 11.32.4 (build 15).

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem just like this.

1) Connect to the db with mysql workbench (select the "use old auth" and "send pass in cleartext"

2) Using the workbench, run:

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0;
SET PASSWORD FOR canningi_cdtest=PASSWORD('testpass');
```

3) Now go back to your app and it should run...

That is how I did it at least. I am using IX mysql and they do use old auth on their server so you must do something on your end...